# Largest String Repetition Removal

Tags: arrays, string, compression, substring, dynamic-programming

Given a string S, I want to find the repeated substring of S (we'll call the substring 'X') such that:

- 1 < X.length
- 1 < occurrences of X
- The value `(X.length) * (occurrences of X)` is maximized.

This would **approximate** finding the substring which would provide the greatest compression when replacing all occurrences of the substring with a single token character.

Is this doable in polynomial time?

If not, are there heuristics or approaches to reduce the practical running time of this algorithm?

Comment: Google "suffix tree".

Comment: @MarkAdler care to elaborate? I don't immediately see how a suffix tree could easily be adapted to count repetitions of a substring. A given substring could occur on multiple different branches throughout a suffix tree

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question? Anyway, a suffix tree is a very efficient (the most efficient?) way to find all of occurrences of a substring, as well as things like the longest repeated substring. If _n_ is the length of the string, _m_ is the length of the substring, and _z_ is number of occurrences, you can find all of them in O( _n_ ) + O( _m_ + _z_ ) time.

Comment: But how would you then efficiently *find* the *best* substring? In other words, how would you find the substring which maximizes `(X.length) * (occurrences of X)`?

Comment: The suffix tree also very efficiently finds the longest repeating substring, and next longest, and so on. Just step through them to check your metric.

Comment: What about overlaps? ABABAB has X.length * occurrences = 8.